# Is it possible to get an SSL certificate for a website or service accessible only locally?

Tags: ssl, networking, ssl-certificate

For example, if I own *domain.tld* and want to host something on *sub.domain.tld* (it resolves to a local address eg. *192.168.xx.xx*), can I get a non self-signed SSL certificate for it?

- I know I can make a self-signed certificate. This is what I am currently doing, but it causes browser warnings and other problems with apps that expect a non self-signed certificate.
- I am aware that I could create my own CA, but then I would have to install the certificate into all my devices. This is cumbersome, and unfeasible for un-rooted android phones.
- I am currently making this service available only on my local network for security. I do not want it facing the internet. As I own the domain, I could easily host it using the public IP, and get an SSL certificate. However, this presents a lot of security concerns. A possible solution would be to password protect everything using basic access authentication, which is less secure than having it internally.

Comment: In short: use [Let's Encrypt DNS challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge) to prove ownership over the domain by showing that you can change DNS entries.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get a valid and publicly signed SSL Certificate for any valid hostname under a domain you control.

Better yet, you can get one for free with Let's Encrypt.  To do it you'd have to give your host access to create DNS record or put something publicly facing to verify you own the domain.  It's the best option for certificate when possible because it take the renewal out of the equation.

The Ip to which the hostname name resolves doesn't matter.  Certificates are done by hostname.  As long as the cert Common Name or SAN (Server alternative name) matches the hostname requested, the cert will be valid.

Comment: Thank you. I got everything to work now, using Let's Encrypt. The key was in using [DNS-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) instead of HTTP-01 which would require having port 80 and 443 open.